# Nodejs each and foreach loop

Tags: node.js

What is each and forEach loop in Nodejs? I am getting my output using each but facing problem using forEach.

```
var MongoClient=require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/"
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err){throw err}
    var dbo=db.db("NewDataBase");
    var pointer=dbo.collection("Collection").find();

    pointer.each(function(err,doc){        
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log(doc);
    })
db.close();
});
```

Comment: `each` is a method that Mongo provides on that `pointer` object.

Comment: Post the code that is not working, and explain why it isn't. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer` is actually a reference to a cursor which you get from the query `dbo.collection("Collection").find();`. And the cursor holds the set of result documents it get from that query. To access those documents you use `each()` and not `forEach()`. This is also because the `forEach()` is a prototype function of Array type data structure but `pointer` is a cursor type data structure so you cannot use that in this case.